# How to call CanExecute when validation cancels UpdateSourceTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, viewmodel

I am using a `ValidationRule` on a `TextBox` in my View, and that `ValidationRule` is working properly.

However, a problem arises when I am in the state where the canExecute method for a `Command` (on a `Button` in this case) has returned true (`Button` is enabled), and then the user changes the contents of the `TextBox` so the `ValidationRule` returns a false `ValidationResult`.  This results in the ViewModel property bound to the `Button.Text` not being updated, which means the canExecute method still thinks results are good and returns true.

So - how can I get the ViewModel property in question to update in spite of the false `ValidationResult`?  Or is there another way of doing all this?

Edit:Here is the XAML for my `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="MachineNo" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:MachineNoValidate/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, the solution appears to be implementing the `IDataErrorInfo` interface on my ViewModel.  I then have full access to the current contents of the `TextBox` through the bound property.

Here is the new XAML:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27"
         Text="{Binding MachineNo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
         ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

Only `this[]` needs to be implemented; WPF does not use the `Error` property.